# FireAllRules() and StartProcess() not producing effect

Tags: java, drools, jbpm, bpmn, business-process-management

hope someone can help me on this. So, I have some local bpmn processes that I imported from BPMS from RedHat. Now I am trying to execute them, as well as some .drl files, with no success on both tries. This is what I am trying:

```
     KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
     Resource ruleFile = ResourceFactory.newFileResource("src/main/resources/rules0.drl");
     Resource ruleFile1 = ResourceFactory.newFileResource("src/main/resources/rules0.drl");
     Resource process1 = ResourceFactory.newFileResource("src/main/resources/Process1.bpmn");
     kbuilder.add(ruleFile,ResourceType.DRL);
     kbuilder.add(ruleFile1,ResourceType.DRL);
     kbuilder.add(process1,ResourceType.BPMN2);

     KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();

     kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());                       StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
     ksession.fireAllRules();
     ksession.startProcess(process1.getSourcePath());
```

But I have tried also :

```
    KieServices kServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieRepository kRepository = kServices.getRepository();
    KieFileSystem kFileSystem = kServices.newKieFileSystem();
     Resource ruleFile = ResourceFactory.newFileResource("src/main/resources/rules0.drl");
    kFileSystem.write(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("rules0.drl"));
    KieBuilder kBuilder = kServices.newKieBuilder(kFileSystem);
    kBuilder.add(ruleFile,ResourceType.DRL);
    kBuilder.buildAll();

KieContainer kContainer =
    kServices.newKieContainer(kRepository.getDefaultReleaseId());
    KieBase kBase = kContainer.getKieBase();
    KieSession kisession = kBase.newKieSession();
    int tot = kisession.fireAllRules();

    System.out.println(""+tot);
```

totalRules is zero and the rule was never fired. In both cases, if I try to start processes(and only if) it will come to:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jbpm.bpmn2.BPMN2ProcessProviderImpl.configurePackageBuilder(Lorg/kie/internal/builder/KnowledgeBuilder;)V

If I only try to fire rules then nothimg happens and tot is 0. The rules are simple rules that only execute a syso. Am I missing something here ? The rules are at src/main/resources/ on my maven project. Sorry for such a gigantic post!

Comment: Are you using Drools 5 or 6? The first example code you provide refers to classes from Drools 5 and the second example uses classes from Drools 6. Although as @salaboy mentions, you don't seem to be inserting any facts, so unless you have rules written to activate with no facts in working memory, then none of your rules should activate.

Comment: Thank you Steve, Salaboy already solved it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you are not insert any fact at all, so I do believe that no rules will be fired, because there are no facts to evaluate basically. 
Regarding starting a process, it seems that there is some dependency missing in your project. Make sure that jbpm-bpmn2 is inside the classpath of your application

HTH